# routing trouble since upgrade sf2.0 to sf2.2

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.2

I made an upgrade of my SF version (2.0.18 to 2.2) and i have trouble with render routing on a twig template.

Error message :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No route found for "GET Security:login"") in "OlrLoanBundle:Default:index.html.twig".

my layout :

```
<body>
            <div id="main" class="container">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                  <div class="span4">
                      <img src="{{ asset('img/logo.jpg') }}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="span8">
                    {% render "FOSUserBundle:Security:login" %}
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/pub.jpg') }}"/>
                  </div>
              </div>        
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="left a-left">
                {% block footer %}
                {% endblock %}
                {% block javascripts %}
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
     </body>
```

i have the same trouble on a template :

```
   {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
    {% block content %}
     <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="span7">

        {% render "OlrLoanBundle:Demande:index" %}
        {% render "OlrLoanBundle:Demande:tribu" %}
        {% render "OlrLoanBundle:Objet:index" %}
     </div>
      </div>
    <div class="span5">
    <img src="{{ asset('img/pub-carre.jpg') }}"/>
    {% render "OlrLoanBundle:Tribu:index" %}

    </div>
  </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, happened to me as well. This is, however, desired behavior as it is stated in official blog:

> Since Symfony 2.0.20/2.1.5, the Twig render tag now takes an absolute
>   url instead of a controller logical path. This fixes an important
>   security issue ([CVE-2012-6431](http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-symfony-2-0-20-and-2-1-5-released)) reported on the official blog. If your
>   application uses an older version of Symfony or still uses the
>   previous render tag syntax, you should upgrade as soon as possible.

Good luck fixing code ;)